# Sculpting Cursor Form

Tags: sculpting

The shape of my sculpting cursor is elliptic on my cylinder. I don't understand as in edit mode, my cylinder is pretty subdivided.

Any idea where that comes from?

Thanks in advance for the help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object has been scaled in *Object Mode*.
Apply the scale through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Scale* and the cursor will be evenly scaled as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Fantastic, That's working:)!!